# How to prevent dbt from rebuilding incremental tables when source view's columns change?

Tags: continuous-integration, bigdata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, dbt

We have the following structure in dbt:

```
[events (view), with column1, column2, column3]‒‒‒>[incremental1, using column1 from events]
                                             |
                                             |
                                             └‒‒‒‒>[incremental2, using column2 from events]
```

In our continuous integration setup, we run `dbt run --models state:modified+` to avoid running models that were not changed in a PR. However, the problem is that if we change `column3` in `events` (e.g. rename it), both incremental tables, `incremental1` and `incremental2`, will be fully rebuilt which may take an excessively long time, sometimes more than a whole day. Note that neither incremental tables are actually affected by the change in their source as they do not use the changed column in any way.

Is there a way to avoid rebuilding these models while also not having to run all the other models (which is what a simple `dbt run` would do)?

Some additional details:

- our dbt version is 1.0
- our data warehouse engine is Snowflake
- our incremental strategy is `'delete+insert'`

Answer (score 1):

`dbt run` takes an `--exclude` option; you could exclude those long-running tables by name, or tag them. This obviously carries its own risks and maintenance burden.

Another option would be to filter the records in these large tables on a dev or CI run so that they build much more quickly. You could add something like this to the incremental model:

```
{% if target.name != 'prod' %}
where updated_at > current_timestamp() - interval '30 days'
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Those are some useful tips, thank you. However, they seem more like a workaround rather than a proper solution. I think dbt should be smart enough to know which columns have been changed and which are actually used. Do you know where such a feature request could be opened?